# Why pwm directory is empty on linux image for BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I'm currently trying use rust to control brightness of led.
I'm using poky with dunfell branch. After turning on `PWM_SYSFS` flag in menuconfig and appending new .cfg config to kernel I find out that `/sys/class/pwm` is empty.
What am i missing ?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twCAX.png)

Thanks in Advance

Regards, Long

Comment: You probably need to modify your devicetree.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it ?

Comment: @PierreOlivier Can u  give some tips ?